# SQLite "appear the amount of courses for every student whether he is in Attends or not" sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an ER Diagram as shown below

[image: ER Diagram]

for every student I want to appear all courses that addends.
So I use query

```
select studentId,course.courseCode
from student natural left outer join attends
natural left outer join course
```

which gives me all results in right way

[image]

now I want to appear the total amount of courses that a student attends
and I am using this query

```
select studentId,
  (select count(attends.courseCode) 
  from attends natural left outer join student
  )as 'amount'
from student
```

but I am having this result

[image]

How am I supposed to appear the real amount of courses for every student whether he is in Attends or not? That is, a 0 for studentId 6,7,8 and a 2 for studentId 17 etc.
Thank you in advance

**PS1:** If you want more of my tables, please let me know.

**PS2:** I was not sure about the title. If you find that another title fits better, please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `natural join`.  It is entirely dependent on the data structure -- and if that changes, then the semantics of the query change too.  In other words, you cannot read a query and really understand what it is doing.

Then, for this query, first generate a list of all students and courses using `cross join`, then bring in the attendance information:

```
select s.studentId, c.courseCode, count(a.CourseCode)
from student s cross join
     course c left join
     attends a
     on s.studentId = a.studentId and s.courseCode = c.courseCode
group by s.studentId, c.courseCode;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't give me the results I expected...in my example, studentId 17 attends 2 courses and it returns that it attends one

Comment: and something else: Could I use left join istead of natural join? So my query could be `select student.studentId, course.courseCode
from student left join attends using(studentId)
left join course using(courseCode)` ?